# Having issues with multiple javascript slideshows on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

Im having isues with multiple javascript slideshows on a single webpage. I can get the one slide show setup to work fine, but when I put others on, I think the scripts are counteracting eachother. Please help.

Here is the js in the header:

```
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "images/linen/ldp-1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "images/linen/ldp-2.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "images/linen/ldp-3.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "images/linen/ldp-4.jpg"
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var image5 = new Image()
image5.src = "images/linen/ldp-5.jpg"
var image6 = new Image()
image6.src = "images/linen/ldp-6.jpg"
var image7 = new Image()
image7.src = "images/linen/ldp-7.jpg"
var image8 = new Image()
image8.src = "images/linen/ldp-8.jpg"
</script>
```

And here is the body:

```
<div align="center">
         <img src="images/linen/ldp-1.jpg" width="300" height="300" name="slide" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step=1;
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
        if(step<2)
            step++;
        else
            step=1;
        setTimeout("slideit()",3000);
    }
    slideit();
</script>

<img src="images/linen/ldp-5.jpg" width="300" height="300" name="slide" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step=1;
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
        if(step<2)
            step++;
        else
            step=1;
        setTimeout("slideit()",3000);
    }
    slideit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a different step variable for the second step.

Comment: Sorry, very new to java... not sure how to do that... I pulled this off of Google, and was hoping it would work if I just replicated it